# Is it possible to find an index of a randomly-chosen JavaScript Object property (if said property is an array/object)?

Tags: javascript, object, random, properties, nested

```js
var geartable = {
  shittyboots: {
    name: "Shitty Boots",
    cost: "500"
  },
  shittyarmor: {
    name: "Shitty Armor",
    cost: "1000"
  },
  shittyhelmet: {
    name: "Shitty Helmet",
    cost: "750"
  }
};

var shops = {
  positions: [
    [2, 3],
    [0, 1],
    [2, 4]
  ],
  inventory: [
    [geartable.shittyboots.name, geartable.shittyboots.cost, "Available"],
    [geartable.shittyarmor.name, geartable.shittyarmor.cost, "Available"],
    [geartable.shittyhelmet.name, geartable.shittyhelmet.cost, "Available"]
  ]
};

function pickRandomItem(gearlist) {
  var result;
  var count = 0;
  for (var item in gearlist) {
    if (Math.random() < 1 / ++count) {
      result = item;
    }
  }
  console.log(geartable.result.cost);
  return result;
}
```

Hi there. So, my problem, put simply, is that I'm trying to access an index/a property of a parent object property, but when I run the random selector function (pickRandomItem) on geartable and try to access a property of the result, it tells me that geartable.result.cost is undefined. I assume this is because, for some god forsaken reason, JavaScript is trying to find a property 'result' inside of geartable instead of looking for a property with the value of result inside of geartable.

Is there any way around this? I'm at the end of my rope and I can't imagine there is, due to the fact that object nesting is already pretty shifty as-is. I've tried this with arrays in the place of nested objects, but geartable.result[0]... etc still returns undefined.

This is the error in the JavaScript console, if you're curious:

```
pickRandomItem(geartable);
TypeError: geartable.result is undefined; can't access its "cost" property[Learn More]
```

Comment: I *think* I see.  Do you want `geartable[result].cost`?

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is:

```
for (var item in gearlist) {
  // ...
  result = item;
// ...
console.log(geartable.result.cost);
```

`for..in` loops iterate over *property names* (not values), and `result` never becomes a property of `geartable`. If you wanted to put a `result` property on the object, you would have to explicitly assign it:

```
for (var item in gearlist) {
  if (Math.random() < 1 / ++count) {
    gearlist.result = gearlist[item];
  }
}
```

And then you could access `gearlist.result` in the future. Or, if you don't want to mutate the input object, just assign to the `result` variable, and to access the result later, access the `result` variable name later, not the `geartable.result` property.

Another problem is that the `if (Math.random() < 1 / ++count)` test is not balanced - objects occurring later will be more likely to be chosen than objects occurring earlier. A balanced random result can be produced by choosing a random item from an array of the object values, by using `Math.random()` only once:

```
const values = Object.values(gearlist);
const randomValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
console.log(randomValue.cost);
return randomValue;
```

```js
var geartable = {
  shittyboots: {
    name: "Shitty Boots",
    cost: "500"
  },
  shittyarmor: {
    name: "Shitty Armor",
    cost: "1000"
  },
  shittyhelmet: {
    name: "Shitty Helmet",
    cost: "750"
  }
};

var shops = {
  positions: [
    [2, 3],
    [0, 1],
    [2, 4]
  ],
  inventory: [
    [geartable.shittyboots.name, geartable.shittyboots.cost, "Available"],
    [geartable.shittyarmor.name, geartable.shittyarmor.cost, "Available"],
    [geartable.shittyhelmet.name, geartable.shittyhelmet.cost, "Available"]
  ]
};

function pickRandomItem(gearlist) {
  const values = Object.values(gearlist);
  const randomValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
  console.log(randomValue.cost);
  return randomValue;
}
pickRandomItem(geartable);
```

Comment: Yep! That seems to be the case. Thanks, man. I was just labeling it wrong. geartable[result].cost, not geartable.result.cost. Apologies for the duplicate question, couldn't find it anywhere.